# Solving complicated logarithmic equation symbolically

Tags: logarithms, symbolic-computation

For a research application, I am trying to solve this system for the variable $c$. I have tried WolframAlpha and Sympy to no avail, so I was wondering if there was a program or tool that would be able to solve this. Maybe a Taylor expansion is the best approach?

\begin{equation*}
\frac{m + d(-ln(1 - a^{3}(c+f)))}{q + r(-ln(1 - a^{3}(c+f)))} - c = 0
\end{equation*}

The Sympy code I tried was

```
import sympy as sym

m,d,a,c,f,q,r = sym.symbols('m d a c f q r')
RHS = c
LHS = (m+d*(-sym.log(1-a**3*(c+f)))) / (q+r*(-sym.log(1-a**3*(c+f))))
result_of_it = sym.solve(LHS-RHS, c)
print(result_of_it)
```

Comment: By "complex equation", do you mean an equation $\in \Bbb C$, or a *complicated/difficult equation*?  If it is the latter, please remove the *complex*, as it is misleading.

Comment: @RhysHughes resolved

Comment: Since $c$ is both *inside* and *outside* the logarithms, the equation is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). The value of $c$ can only be approximated with numerical methods.

Comment: If $c$ is suppose to be "small", a series expansion could give an approximation.